# Converting Laravel "return view($this->theme" to return Json data

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, laravel-api

I bought this Codecanyon WebApp project which i want to use the APIs to develop a mobile version (fluter & Dart) of same system, only for me to realise theres no API i can use to integrate those features using Flutter and dart for Mobile app... some codes below

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

web.php ( since the file is long i just copied some part of it

```
/*====Manage Users ====*/
        Route::get('/users', 'Admin\UsersController@index')->name('users');
        Route::get('/users/search', 'Admin\UsersController@search')->name('users.search');
        Route::post('/users-active', 'Admin\UsersController@activeMultiple')->name('user-multiple-active');
        Route::post('/users-inactive', 'Admin\UsersController@inactiveMultiple')->name('user-multiple-inactive');
        Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@userEdit')->name('user-edit');
        Route::post('/user/update/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@userUpdate')->name('user-update');
        Route::post('/user/password/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@passwordUpdate')->name('userPasswordUpdate');
        Route::post('/user/balance-update/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@userBalanceUpdate')->name('user-balance-update');

        Route::get('/user/send-email/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@sendEmail')->name('send-email');
        Route::post('/user/send-email/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@sendMailUser')->name('user.email-send');
        Route::get('/user/transaction/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@transaction')->name('user.transaction');
        Route::get('/user/fundLog/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@funds')->name('user.fundLog');
        Route::get('/user/payoutLog/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@payoutLog')->name('user.withdrawal');
        Route::get('/user/escrowLog/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@escrowLog')->name('user.escrow');


        Route::get('/email-send', 'Admin\UsersController@emailToUsers')->name('email-send');
        Route::post('/email-send', 'Admin\UsersController@sendEmailToUsers')->name('email-send.store');
```

homeController.php (just copied some methods from it)

```
 public function addFund()
    {

        $data['totalPayment'] = null;
        $data['gateways'] = Gateway::where('status', 1)->orderBy('sort_by', 'ASC')->get();
        return view($this->theme . 'user.addFund', $data);
    }


    public function profile()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        $languages = Language::all();
        return view($this->theme . 'user.profile.myprofile', compact('user', 'languages'));
    }

    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {

        $allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');

        $image = $request->image;
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => [
                'required',
                'max:4096',
                function ($fail) use ($image, $allowedExtensions) {
                    $ext = strtolower($image->extension());
                    if (!in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)) {
                        return $fail("Only png, jpg, jpeg images are allowed");
                    }else{
                        if (($image->getSize() / 1000000) > 2) {
                            return $fail("Images MAX  2MB ALLOW!");
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        ]);
        $user = $this->user;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $path = config('location.user.path');
            try {
                $user->image = $this->uploadImage($image, $path);
            } catch (\Exception $exp) {
                return back()->with('error', 'Could not upload your ' . $image)->withInput();
            }
        }
        $user->save();
        return back()->with('success', 'Updated Successfully.');
    }
```

How can i get/convert this to return Json that i can use on my flutter project and how easy can it be to implement as a junior dev?

thanks... i just need help on this

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = ['success' => 1, 'msg' => 'Updated Successfully.'];
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: Code based answers should also include some tips / description of the functions used.